# warnings with c program compiling :assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]

Tags: c

when I compiling the a program named Online_ana.c (by running a makefile) with following line:

```
if ((fifoFile = open((FIFO1!=NULL) ? FIFO1 : "fifo1", O_RDONLY)) == -1)
```

encountered with such warnings:

> Online_ana.c:54:17: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]

whats is wrong with that?
Hope that someone can help me. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: How is `fifoFile` declared?

Comment: `fifoFile` seems to be not of type `int`.

Comment: Either fifoFile is expecting a pointer such as a File *  from fopen(), or else FIFO1 is not a string (character array pointer).

Comment: If `fifoFile` is declared as `FILE*`, you should be using `fopen()`, not `open()`.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple things wrong with this.

1)You're assigning an integer value to a pointer.  This isn't always wrong, but it is suspicious.  It usually means a bug, but there are some situations where its ok.  THat's why the compiler spits out a warning rather than an error.  You should assure that you mean it.

2)Like @Barmar said, open returns an integer (a file handle) not a FILE*.  If you're assigning one to the other its wrong.

3)Slightly unrelated, but assigning and comparing in an if like that is almost always a bad idea.  Its too easy to accidentally type = somewhere you meant == and cause bugs.  It should be avoided, use 1 line for assignment and 1 for comparison.  I know old school C style is to use a single line, but these days its considered a bad idea.